# SQL Possible Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

For a while now i have been trying to teach myself to pivot in SQL but what i need i can't quite do.

I need it to look at the ID then create columns for the code type and sort then give it's code.

Current Statement:

```
Select ID, CodeType, Sort, Code 
From Coding
```

What I have:

```
ID      | CodeType  | Sort  | Code
78422   | DIAN      | 1     | Q123
78422   | DIAN      | 2     | P223
78422   | DIAN      | 3     | F323
78422   | PROE      | 1     | D423
78422   | PROE      | 2     | I124
13478   | DIAN      | 1     | P224
13478   | DIAN      | 2     | B324
13478   | DIAN      | 3     | Q424
13478   | DIAN      | 4     | A125
13478   | PROE      | 1     | P225
13478   | PROE      | 2     | Y325
13478   | PROE      | 3     | E425
```

What I need:

```
ID      | DIAN1 | DIAN2 | DIAN3 | DIAN4 | PROE1 | PROE2 | PROE3
78422   | Q123  | P223  | F323  | NULL  | D423  | I124  | NULL
13478   | P224  | B324  | Q424  | A125  | P225  | Y325  | E425
```

I am MS SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Will there only ever be a maximum of 4 `DIAN` and 3 `PROE` values or is this meant to stand for a more generic "any unique combination of `CodeType` and `Sort` columns should become an output column"?

Comment: There can be up to 13 for each CodeType

Comment: Did you tried my answer below?

Comment: I did, but when i ran it in MS SQL Server Management Studio it error on the Declare @.

Comment: can you send me the error message?

Comment: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: what version of SQL server your using?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following.

Fiddler Demo:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4a381/2

**Query:**

```
Declare @columns varchar(max)

select @columns = STUFF((Select distinct ','+CodeType + cast(Sort as varchar(2)) from DataInfo
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

Print @columns

Declare @qry nvarchar(max)

set @qry = 'Select * from
(
Select id,Code,CodeType + cast(Sort as varchar(2)) as OrderInfo from DataInfo
)
as t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Code)
    FOR OrderInfo in ('+@columns+')
) as P;'

print @qry

execute sp_executesql  @qry
```

Hope it helps!